# IAsyncOperation await in Windows Service: "Type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced..."

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, windows-services, async-await, windows-10-desktop

I have a Windows Service (created using this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx)).

And I am trying to run an `IAsyncOperation`:

```
var uri= new Uri(@"uri/to/second/app");
var options = new LauncherOptions
{
   TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = "second-app-guid"
};
var results = await Launcher.LaunchUriForResultsAsync(uri, options);
```

However, I get the following error from the `await`:

- `The type 'IAsyncOperationWithProgress<,>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.`
- `The type 'IAsyncOperation<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.`
- `The type 'IAsyncActionWithProgress<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.`
- `The type 'IAsyncAction' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.`

I have looked this error up and a lot of people said that it is due to a VS installation error but, performing a clean install (whilst checking the checksums of the ISOs) failed to solve the problem.

Also, I tried this in a blank Universal Windows App and this error didn't appear. So I wonder if this is even possible in a Windows Service? (.NET Framework version 4.6.1)

Comment: You're running as a service. There may be *no* users logged on when you're running. There may be *multiple* users logged on when you're running. You can't launch an app - services aren't allowed to interact with desktops, even if one does exist,

Answer (score 6):

According to your code, it seems you want to use UWP APIs in a Windows Service application and from your error, I'd suppose the problem here is because you are missing **References** in your project.

To call UWP APIs from a classic .NET Framework application, we should add the following two references:

- Firstly, we need to add a reference to the metadata file that contains the definition of all the supported APIs: it’s called **Windows.md** and we can find it in the following path on our computer: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata**.
- The second is **System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll** and we can find it in the following path: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5**. Without this DLL, we can't use use `await` on WinRT types, this and other interop between .NET and WinRT are provided by this DLL.

Besides, we can also using [UWPDesktop NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UwpDesktop/10.0.14393.3) instead of above two references. For more info, please see [Calling Windows 10 APIs From a Desktop Application](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application).

> So I wonder if this is even possible in a Windows Service? (.NET Framework version 4.6.1)

However, even you fixed these compiler error, your code still can't work. This is because `Launcher.LaunchUriForResultsAsync` is not an API supported in standard desktop applications & Windows Service. So it is not allowed to use `Launcher.LaunchUriForResultsAsync` method in **Windows Service**, even `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` method is not workable in Windows Service.

Comment: What if the folder `.../10/UnionMetadata` does not contain `Windows.winmd`? It contains subfolders for the different SDKs; in my case, `/10.0.19041.0/Windows.winmd`. Does this still work?

Answer (score 0):

Download the `Windows 10 SDK` at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk. Then add `Windows.winmd` and `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll` as your references. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have to add `Windows 10 SDK` to the Visual Studio installation.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding more dependencies, it's better to try to remove them, to stop this cancer spreading. The core problem is the Nuget package of `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime` which tries to load these, and whenever you e.g. use reflection, the dependencies are also loaded.

It's some old WinRT things, but it seems that packages like `System.Net.Http` has it still in dependencies. But it's only needed in ".NET Core 5.0" which is a deprecated alias for UAP10.0. So if you can restrict your dependencies targetframeworks to exclude that, it should fix the problem.