# depth and infrared frame on a surface pro

Tags: c#, uwp, surface-pro

I ran the sample UWP application CameraFrames found in https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraFrames which is supposed to grab the infra red and depth frames. However I have never got those frames. I can see the rgb frame fine. I am running the application on a surface pro that has does have an infra camera.

Is there something I am missing?

I also tried the sample on another machine with an Intel RealSense camera and still no luck. Though I wasn't sure if this camera was supported by this UWP API.

Comment: Can you show the model information about your surface pro and Intel RealSense camera? And if you test the sample on PC, then change another camera, will the same issue occur?

Comment: The camera in the surface pro is AVStream Camera 2500. It supports a depth and infra red. I know it works because I can use windows sign-in by face. However using the UWP sample code the infra frame isn't shown.

Comment: Can you capture an MFTrace based on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/using-mftrace) ?
That should tell us whether the depth and infrared camera are made available by the driver. In addition, if you have the inf file for the camera driver that would be helpful.